# Why does my program output the wrong highest number?

Tags: python, arrays, list, max

When I run this program, it says that the max number is 1 digit lower than it actually is in the list. For example, I run the code below and it tells me the max number is 91 when it is 92 from the list.

```
examMarks = [[80, 59, 34, 89], [31, 11, 47, 64], [29, 56, 13, 92]]

for eachRow in range(len(examMarks)):
    for eachColumn in range(len(examMarks[eachRow])):
        eachExamMark = (examMarks[eachRow][eachColumn])


max = -100
for everyMark in range(eachExamMark): 
    if everyMark > max:
        max = everyMark
print(max)
```

Comment: Have you debugged it to see at what point the data changes?

Comment: This code doesn't do what you think it does. At all. I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to figure out what's going on this program.

Comment: Hint, add `print(eachExamMark)` above `max = -100`. The code don't seem to do what you think it does.

Comment: Using `max` as a variable name isn't a good idea since it is a built-in function name (a built-in function that would be helpful for what you are trying to do: there is a 1-line expression that will compute the max of the maxes).

Comment: There is the elegant solution: maxMark = max([max(x) for x in examMarks])

Comment: @DenisKuzin no real reason for the square brackets in that comprehension -- why build the list in memory?

Comment: @JohnColeman, thanks. Yes, the better solution is maxMark = max(max(x) for x in examMarks)

Comment: A construct like `for x in range(len(...))` is almost always an indication you are doing something the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this code!

```
examMarks = [[80, 59, 34, 89], [31, 11, 47, 64], [29, 56, 13, 12]]
eachExamMark =[]
for eachRow in range(len(examMarks)):
    for eachColumn in range(len(examMarks[eachRow])):
        eachExamMark.append(examMarks[eachRow][eachColumn])


max = -100
for everyMark in eachExamMark: 
    if everyMark > max:
        max = everyMark
print(max)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the reason for the 3 loops to be honest, have you tried something like this?

```
examMarks = [[80, 59, 34, 89], [31, 11, 47, 64], [29, 56, 13, 92]]
highest = 0


for marks in examMarks:
    for mark in marks:
        highest = max(mark, highest)

print('Highest mark: %d' % highest)
```

Comment: Although this is a better way to come to the correct answer of what is the maximum, this doesn't help the OP understand why (s)he is getting 91 as answer

Answer (score 1):

`eachExamMark` will be set to `(92)` that is the number `92` as the last step of the first part of your program. If you do a for loop over `range(92)` it will end at `91`.

You should at least do:

```
 print(eachExamMark)
```

before the `max = -100` line.

You probably want to do:

```
   eachExamMark.append(examMarks[eachRow][eachColumn])
```

after defining `eachExamMark = []` at the beginning.

I am not sure if you have to solve things this way, but IMHO you should not be using `range()` **at all**, and there is no need to build a flattened list either.

You could e.g. do:

```
examMarks = [[80, 59, 34, 89], [31, 11, 47, 64], [29, 56, 13, 92]]
print(max(max(x) for x in examMarks))
```

Answer (score 0):

As others point out the problem is the last loop is performing a range of a number, not a list as you expect.

An alternative algorithm:

```
from itertools import chain
examMarks = [[80, 59, 34, 89], [31, 11, 47, 64], [29, 56, 13, 92]]
print(max(chain.from_iterable(examMarks)))
```

`chain.from_iterable(examMarks)` flattens the list to an iterator

`max()` finds the maximum number on the list

Note: My original answer used `sum(examMarks, [])` to flatten the list. Thanks @John Coleman for your comment on a faster solution.

Comment: That is clever, but see this: https://mathieularose.com/how-not-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
examMarks = [[80, 59, 34, 89], [31, 11, 47, 64], [29, 56, 13, 12]]
eachExamMark =[]
for eachRow in examMarks:
    eachExamMark.append(max(eachRow))

print max(eachExamMark)
```